# Magento how to convert select option to button in bundle product?

Tags: magento, templates, magento-1.9

I want to customize Bundle product template, convert select option to button "Add Item". Convert select,multiselect,checkbox, radio to button to add instead selection. Anyone have a solution or idea on this? How to achieve this?
Like this:

for select, radio:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/onXgj.png

for multiselect, checkbox:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhOpp.png

thanks for read.

Answer (score 1):

For bundle product template are located in app\design\frontend\base\default\template\bundle\catalog\product\view\type\bundle\option\

Copy the template files in your local theme, and edit the files checkbox.phtml, radio.phtml, select.phtml, etc. according to your need.